# Issue in downloading an image in Delphi

Tags: delphi, url, download, idhttp

I am writing an image downloader software. But I have problem to download some images such as:

https://books.google.com/books/content?id=8_pCYmpCu6UC&pg=PT4&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U10JF_yd0n7gvCllBts88O_ufTWxA&w=1280

You can check it in your browser (You should see a page with 1.Introduction title. If you could not see, it is related to your region restriction. Using US proxy would solve it).

I'm using Delphi 10.3 update 2 in Win 10. My project is 32 version.

1-I used TIdHttp to download the file but I got another image (An Image with this content: "Image not available").

```
procedure DownloadeImage(FURL, FFileName :string);
var
  HTTPClient: TIdHTTP;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
    HTTPClient.HandleRedirects := True;
    HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
    //HTTPClient.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    //(HTTPClient.IOHandler as TIdOpenSSLIOHandlerClient).Options.VerifyServerCertificate := False;
    HTTPClient.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0'; //'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    HTTPClient.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
    try
      FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmCreate);
      try
        HTTPClient.Get(FURL, FileStream); //(TIdURI.URLEncode(FURL), FileStream);
      finally
        FileStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      HTTPClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    // error handling ignored for this example
  end;
end;
```

2-The same result when using TNetHttpClient

```
procedure DownloadeImage(FURL, FFileName :string);
var
  HTTPClient: TNetHTTPClient;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    HTTPClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
    HTTPClient.HandleRedirects := True;
    HTTPClient.AllowCookies := True;
    //HTTPClient.SecureProtocols := [THTTPSecureProtocol.SSL2, THTTPSecureProtocol.SSL3, THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS1, //THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS11, THTTPSecureProtocol.TLS12];
    //HTTPClient.Accept := 'image/png, image/gif, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/tif, image/tiff, image/bmp, //image/x-bmp;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
    HTTPClient.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0';
    try
      FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmCreate);
      try
        HTTPClient.Get(FURL, FileStream); //(TIdURI.URLEncode(FURL), FileStream);
      finally
        FileStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      HTTPClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    // error handling ignored for this example
  end;
end;
```

3-But I get the goal using the following code:

```
URLMon.URLDownloadToFile(nil, PChar(FURL), PChar(FFileName), 0, nil)
```

Why?!!!
I think it is related to some default value of TIdhttp and TNetHttpClient or about some SSL protocol.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be downloading these images.

Comment: You are wrong! The image is part of allowed pages. Restricted pages can not be downloaded by no means.

Comment: All browser can open the URL. Restricted pages cannot be open in the browsers too.

Comment: Aren't developers supposed to use documented APIs?

Comment: Note that I gave a sample URL.
As I told, I have a solution for it (third way). Also, another solution is using ImageEn component that implement download from URL using APIs.
So, My goal is not download the file. My focus is difference between TIdhhtp, TNetHttp and what browser really do.

Comment: I am not sure how you intend to comply with the Branding Guidelines for Google Books without using the Embedded Viewer API. Showing a naked preview image does not comply with the branding guidelines.

Comment: As I mentioned, I gave only a sample URL. I wondered to the answers.
I'm investing in TNetHttp. I need to know its restrictions.

Comment: Google's `NID` cookie is not sent in your both attempts, while `UrlMon` sends it from any previous activity. This can be analyzed by inspecting the network activity in any web browser by requesting your URI.

Comment: @aestemp "*My focus is difference between TIdhhtp, TNetHttp and what browser really do*" - then you should be looking at their actual network traffics to see what is different between the HTTP messages they exchange with the server.

Comment: Dear AmigoJack
Thank you so much.
You are right. It was related to the cookies.

Comment: Dear Lebeau
How can I monitor network traffic for similar purpose?

Comment: Dear AmigoJack.
Please write your comment as an answer.